# Connect to MySQL in RDS using Java Connector/J and SSL

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, jdbc, mysql-connector

I am struggling to get my java code (that uses [`HikariCP`](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem)) to connect with my `database` on `AWS RDS` using `SSL`. I can connect with the `database` using `MySQL Workbench`, I just can't find out how to configure the `MySQL Connector/J 5.1.45` driver to access the `database` using `SSL`.

Currently this is my `HikariCP` properties file:

```
jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://mypath.jqwejrkq4568833.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/myschema
username=myusername
password=mypassword
dataSource.cachePrepStmts=true
dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize=250
dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
dataSource.useServerPrepStmts=true
dataSource.useLocalSessionState=true
dataSource.useLocalTransactionState=true
dataSource.rewriteBatchedStatements=true
dataSource.cacheResultSetMetadata=true
dataSource.cacheServerConfiguration=true
dataSource.elideSetAutoCommits=true
dataSource.maintainTimeStats=false
dataSource.clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file://truststore
dataSource.clientCertificateKeyStorePassword=123456
dataSource.useSSL=true
dataSource.verifyServerCertificate=true
dataSource.requireSSL=true
```

The `truststore` file was generated with the `RDS` [certificate from here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem), it's on my `classpath` root since it's on my `resources` folder from `maven`. I really want to provide my own `truststore` file to the `MySQL Connector/J` driver so this program can be moved around without having to configure the `truststore` from the environment (this is very useful for me because my code runs locally on `GlassFish` but on the cloud on `AWS Lambda` and who knows where will it run tomorrow).

When I try to get a connection using this configuration I get the following error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot open file://truststore [truststore]

At first I thought my `trustore` `url` was wrong, but if I change it to something like this:

```
dataSource.clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:///truststore
```

The error changes to:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot open file:///truststore [\truststore (The system cannot find the file specified)]

Which indicates for me that the first `url` was correct.

I have no idea what am I doing wrong or how to fix this, the `truststore was generated with the following command:

```
'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\keytool.exe' -importcert -alias AwsRdsMySqlCACert -file rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem -keystore truststore -storepass 123456
```

I have no idea what am I doing wrong, which leads me to the question:

**What's wrong with my `truststore` file then?**

---

EDIT:

Digging deeper I could find the cause of the `Exception`:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot open file://truststore [truststore]

is:

> java.net.UnknownHostException: truststore

I don't know what this means since my `database` `url` is correct because it's the same I use in `MySQL Workbench`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Maven, make sure you are using the  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/home/vagrant with the proper certificate , or configure the MAVEN_OPTS with the proper value for example : -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/dev, also place it on the runner section in Intellij